# setting up apache web server - noob question

Tags: apache

i am new to apache web server, i am simply trying to create a single html file website viewable to all served from my computer. I have located where the default text file is, but after using a web proxy i realized the proxy could not reach my website. this probably sounds rudimentary to you but would you know where in the httpd file i should modify to make this work?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is connected directly with Internet, you should allow access to port 80 from outside, and change the listening address too (Listen *:80).

if your computer is behind a router, your router should be configured to forward incoming requests on port 80 to your computer.